# Opentracing module for Haproxy

Tags: haproxy, opentracing

I am looking for an Opentracing module for HAProxy

I have Spring applications running behind an Haproxy instance and I want to see a distributed trace from: haproxy => Java applications => databases

It seems like this is possible in NGINX through the [Opentracing module](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/opentracing/) but Haproxy doesn't have a plugin for this